# How can I create a client via redux toolkit and using apollo and use graphql?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, redux-toolkit

I'm new in this field. I'm very confused and need help.

How can I perform all GraphQL queries and mutations via Redux Toolkit?

(I should use the mutation only to get the token information while the user is logging in.)

While doing these, I need to use client.mutate / client.query instead of useQuery and useMutation, but I couldn't find any examples anywhere.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already use Apollo, you should not be using Redux Toolkit for api requests on to of that. Apollo is already a full-fledged api client & cache. You don't need to add a hand-written cache layer on top of that.

In this case you can still use Redux to manage non-api application state, but don't use it to do Apollo's job.